# Defined array value shows as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting the following error on my console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

```js
age= 55;
array = new Array();
array[55] = [8.7, 7.5];
array[56] = [8.9, 7.6];
array[57] = [9, 7.7];
array[58] = [9.2, 7.8];
array[59] = [9.4, 7.9];
array[60] = [9.6, 8];

data = array[age];
console.log( data[0] + " | " + data[1] );
```

Comment: Sparse arrays are bad practice, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @elclanrs am trying to get values from 'data' array

Comment: But why are you starting at index 55? You may want a collection (array of objects), like `[{age: 55, data: [8.7,7.5]}, {...}, {...}]`. Then you can use array methods like `filter` to get what you need.

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the error you are mentioning (as you can see by the stack fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

i test your code,but it doesn't have mistake and output "8.7 | 7.5" correctly.However,when i test it in strict mode,it has mistake because lack of "var" when you define the variable.